# JavaScript test function and EventListner

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

```
async function getValue() {
  const firstName = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
  const lastName = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
  
  await saveData(new Customer(undefined, firstName, lastName));
  dispatchEvent(new Event(DATA_CHANGED_EVENT));
}

document.getElementById("addCustomerForm").addEventListener("submit", getValue);
```

Hello
how to write a test using jest.spyOn for this code snippet?

Comment: What do you want to test? Mock saveData? mock dispatchEvent?

Comment: everything that can be tested is possible: mock saveData, mock dispatchEvent, and call this method by "submit"

Comment: Do you have jsdom ? because by default there is no dom in jest, you need to install and configure it.